# location for images in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I try to create controller for images,
I found this option:

```
@Controller()
@RequestMapping("api/image")
class ImageController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var servContext: ServletContext

    @GetMapping("{name}", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    fun getImage(@PathVariable name: String, h: HttpServletResponse): ByteArray? {
        println(name)

        val inp =  servContext.getResourceAsStream("WHAT IS LOCATION")

        return inp.readAllBytes()
    }
}
```

Where should I put the folder with pictures in the project? No matter what file address I put in  servContext.getResourceAsStream I always get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.InputStream.readAllBytes()" because "inp" is null
```

Comment: Spring has several ways to work with resources, the documentation for them are here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/resources.html.  I place my resources in `/src/main/resources`, but that's a Maven convention.  Where you place yours will be dependent on the build tool that you're using to package your app.